# Java questions using only for-loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm really new to Java programming so i was hoping if any of you could help me with this.

This question lets you practice with a single loop.

(a) Write a program OddSequencer.java that prints the following series 1  2  4  7  11  16 using a for-loop. Hint: Identify the pattern in this sequence first. In particular, what is the difference between two consecutive numbers in this sequence?

Sorry, i wasn't trying to just dump it on you guys. I get that for part (a) there's a pattern in the series of numbers in that it goes from 1 (1+1) -> 2 (2+2) -> 4 (4+3) -> 7 (7+4) -> 11 (11+5) -> 16

What i currently have is

```
public class OddSequencer {
    public static void main(String [] args){
       for(int i = 1; i <= 16; i) // i'm not sure what the last condition is supposed to be
       System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

(b) Write a program called SumLoops.java with a main method that prints out the sum of multiples of 3 from 3 to 30 (inclusive of both 3 and 30) using a for-loop.

What i currently have is

```
public class SumLoops {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        for(int i = 3; i <= 30; i+=3)
            System.out.println(i);   
    }
}
```

The output of your program should look like this:

```
D:\is200\lab1>java SumLoops
Sum of multiples of 3 from 3 to 30 = 165

D:\is200\lab1>
```

Comment: `"i was hoping if any of you could help me with this."` is not a specific answerable question, and instead you need to ask an actual specific question and not just dump your assignment here for us to do. Please have a look at the [help] as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections for more information on how to improve your question and increase your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: Don't post this stuff in comments, but instead **please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32282482/edit) and improve your question**. A little more effort can go a long way.

Comment: I'm sorry if i've angered any of you guys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For a consider this :

```
     /*Outputs a serious of 5 numbers, starting at 1.

      The difference between one number to the next one is
      a sequence of numbers, starting at 1 and incremented by 1
      i.e: 1,2,3,4,5
    */

    //represents the difference between one number and the next one.
    //the first difference is 1. 
    int step = 1;

    //represents the numbers to output. Initialized to first number
    int outputNumber = 1;

    //loop over all steps
    for( step=1;  step <= 6 ; step++){

        //do output
        System.out.print(" "+ outputNumber ) ; 
        outputNumber += step; //add step to get the next output number 
    }
```

for b:

```
        //the sum of multiplies
        int sumOfMultiples =0;

        //loop that runs from i=1 as long as i*30 <=30
        for(int i = 1; (3*i) <=30; i++){

            sumOfMultiples += 3*i;
        }

            System.out.println("Sum of multiples of 3 from 3 to 30 = "+sumOfMultiples);
```

I hope that the comments make it clear.

Comment: Thank you. If I write out the the code for (a) on paper , does it go like this?

s = 1(initial value) + 1(Initial i-value) = 2
s = 2 (new value) + 2(i++) = 4
s = 4(new value) + 3(i++) = 7

and so on..

Comment: @STJJ I Changed variable names and comments to clarify a. I hope it makes the logic clearer. Fell free to ask if it needs more clarification.

Comment: Thank you for being so patient with me! I've gotten how it works! :)